# Drawing circle using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, circle

I want to draw a circle with
1 centerpoint and the radius, or with
3 points.
I am using QGIS 3.10  and EPSG 25832

Comment: Are you asking how to buffer a point by a specific distance?

Comment: Do you want your circle to be a feature in a layer, or a simple screen graphic?

Answer (score 4):

Creating a circle using **QGIS 3.18** (Windows 10 Pro) with 3 points.

[image]

Documentation
[https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=circle#draw-circles][2](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=circle#draw-circles)